# Looping over JSON array using *ngFor

Tags: json, angular

I currently have the following JSON file:

```
[   
{
  "Arsenal": {
    "form": {
      "away": 4.6064800860172,
      "home": 2.2108841763771
    },
    "stadium": "Stadium 1"
  }
},
{
  "Man City": {
    "form": {
      "away": 4.9473459270023,
      "home": 5
    },
    "stadium": "Stadium 2"
  }
},
{
  "Man Utd": {
    "form": {
      "away": 5,
      "home": 3.2296790061981
    },
    "stadium": "Stadium 3"
  }
}
]
```

and I want to display this data in a table. I currently have a service that retrieves the JSON file and returns it

```
public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('assets/teams.json')
    .map(
      (response: Response) => {
        const data = response.json();
        return data;
      }
    );
}
```

I then subscribe to it in my component and save it to `teams`.

```
teams = [];
loadJSON() {
  this.teamService.getJSON().subscribe(
    (teams: any[]) => this.teams = teams,
    (error) => console.log(error)
  );
}
```

and using the following `HTML`

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Home</th>
        <th>Away</th>
        <th>Stadium</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let team of teams | keys">
        <td>{{ (team.value | keys)[0].key }}</td>
        <td>{{ (team.value | keys)[0].value["form"]["home"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ (team.value | keys)[0].value["form"]["away"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ (team.value | keys)[0].value["stadium"] }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

gives the table seen below

[image: Table showing JSON file]

Surely there must be a better way of doing this? How can I do this in a more straight-forward way, that is a lot more readable? For example, if the key was actually "Arsenal", "Man City" and "Man Utd" instead of 0, 1 and 2 respectively, it would be much more readable. Why does it have those keys instead? I'm used to coding in Python so it doesn't really make much sense to me.

A working stackblitz can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbh7dq?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html).

Comment: If you have control over the API, I'd suggest changing the structure. That structure looks really odd: keys should be known values, not the payload data.

Comment: @IngoBürk what would you suggest I change it to?

Comment: It should be something like `{ name: "Arsenal", form: {...}, ... }`. That way you can just iterate over the array directly and the awkwardness goes away. You can use the HTML in @mickaelw's answer, just without needing to go through mapping it to a class.

Comment: @IngoBürk alright, cheers. I simply changed my Python code to make it like that, and it's much easier like you said!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose to have your own `Team` object and map your JSON on it.

So in your **teams.service** you have:

```
public getJSON(): Observable<Team[]> {
  return this.http.get('assets/teams.json')
    .map(teams => teams.map(team => this.mapTeam(team)))
}

private mapTeam(res: any): Team {
  const teamName = Object.keys(res)[0]
  return new Team(
      teamName, 
      {away: res[teamName].form.away, home: res[teamName].form.home}, 
      res[teamName].stadium
  )
}
```

Your **Team class** can be like this:

```
export class Team {

  constructor(public name: string, 
              public form: { away: number, home: number }, 
              public stadium: string) { 
  }

}
```

It's not the subject of your question but in this the Team class it's preferable to have private properties and have getter to access it.

**In your component.ts:**

Just call your service and assign the value of the subscribe: `this.teamService.getJSON().subscribe(value => this.teams = value)`

There are antother way to do this part but it's not your question too

And finally your **html** it's more readable:

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Home</th>
        <th>Away</th>
        <th>Stadium</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let team of teams">
        <td>{{ team.name }} </td>
        <td>{{ team.form.home }}</td>
        <td>{{ team.form.away }}</td>
        <td>{{ team.stadium }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwj6nb

Comment: @Esoemah can you retry it? I just use Observable.of(...) instead of http.get to simulate the json file

Comment: I get the following error when using `http.get`: `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Response'.`.

Comment: @Esoemah I check that I have a 403 on stackblitz with the json

Comment: What? Try doing it with `http.get` instead of `Observable.of`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Alright I managed to get it working by changing `value.json()` to just `value` amongst some other things, so thanks a lot.